# A Partial Integral Equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds

Is there any means to solve the "partial" integral equation of $u$: $$\int_{l} u(x,y) d\mathcal{H}^1=F(a,b,c)$$ (where $l=\{(x,y)|ax+by+c=0, a^2+b^2=1\}$ is a straight line in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\mathcal{H}^1$ is the 1-dimension Hausdorff measure) under the following different conditions?

I.F is continuous on some closed subset of the half cylinder $\Sigma=\{(a,b,c)|a^2+b^2=1,c \ge 0\}$;

II.F is $C^k$ on some open subset of $\Sigma$ seen as a differentiable manifold.

I come up with this problem when I tried to transform between integral equations and differential equations. The transformation is easily obtained in 1-variable situation, but I got stuck in higher dimension.

**Attempt:** Write $x=bs-ac,y=-as-bc$ ($s$ is the length parameter since $a^2+b^2=1$) and the equation is transformed into ($\mathcal{L}^1$ is the 1-dimension Lebesgue measure) $$\int_\Bbb{R}u(bs-ac,-as-bc)d\mathcal{L}^1=F(a,b,c)$$ Assume $u$ to be smooth and absolutely Riemann integrable we can then calculate partial derivates about $a,b,c$ respectively on both sides, however it does not seem to help in grabbing $u$ "out of" the integral symbol.

**Simplification:** You can assume $F$ is globally defined on $\Sigma$ if it helps to construct an simpler procedure.

**Further Simplification:** If $F$ is independent of $a,b$, can we conclude that $u$ has radial symmetry?

**Bonus:** Since $F$ may not be defined on the whole cylinder, the  domain that $u$ can be determined is also interesting, but this question may go too far...

Comment: I am a bit confused since you called $a^2 + b^2 =1$ the cylinder. Are you working in $\mathbb R^3$ or $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @ArcticChar The cylinder is the whole space of lines in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and so is in $\Bbb{R}^3$.